# Redirection to correct App Store page for iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, redirect

i want to redirect users to either iphone or ipad app store page depending on the device used. I have the script that detects the os and redirects to the respective app stores but I need to add this additional step.

Comment: You say you have the script to redirect so what additional step do you need to add? Your question is unclear. You must provide more details and explain what do you actualy need.

Comment: Thank you @francadaval This is the script: ...sorry...quite new here...so trying to find out how to paste the code here.

Comment: <%

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
String  userAgent  =   request.getHeader("User-Agent");
String os;
System.out.println("User Agent for the request is: {0}"+ userAgent);

 if (userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("windows phone") 
            || userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("wp7")) {
     os = "wp";
 } else if(userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("android")) {
     os = "android";
 } else if(userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("iphone")
            || userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("ipad") 
            || userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("ipod")) {

Comment: }
try {
  
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Etisalat eLife ON App</title>");
    if (link != null) {
        out.println("<script>");
        out.println("function redirect(){window.location = \"" + link + "\";}");
        out.println("window.onload = redirect;");
        out.println("</script>");
    }
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    if(link == null){

Comment: out.println("Use your mobile device to access this link. This link is not accessible on your laptop/desktop operating system.");
    }
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

}catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
%>

Comment: Sorry for the very messy pasting above. I need to basically redirect iphone and ipad users to their respective pages in the app store. The above code only redirects ios users to one page. How do I add the logic to redirect them to either iphone or ios?

Comment: You must edit your question. Don't put your code on comments. It's not legible.